# WSO2 Identity Server-number of user sessions

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we are using WSO2 Identity Server As an IDP. we have registered our application www.abcdefg.com as a Service Provider. Now when we access the www.abcdefg.com in any browser, IDP is giving us the page to enter the credentials to authenticate into www.abcdefg.com.

Now what we are looking for is, do we have any WSO2 Product where we can see how many users were authenticated into www.abcdefg.com? or can we achieve this in WSO2 Identity Server Product.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature planned for an upcoming Identity Server release and is currently under development. See the mail ["[Architecture] Security Analytics"](http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/architecture/2016-February/022507.html) at `architecture@wso2.org` mailing list for more details if you are interested :)

Comment: does this project also covers to show number of active sessions, idle sessions,expired sessions and facility to forcibly turning off the sessions etc.

Comment: Showing the number of active and expired sessions will probably be a part of it. However forced session termination will not be available with this release. It is planned with a future release.

Comment: How soon can we expect the WSO2 Identity Server with the above mentioned features.

Comment: According to the current timelines it'll be by the end of Q3 this year.